# Reading text file works in IDE but not in .jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using

```
File file = new File("res/movies.txt");
```

to read text from a bundled .txt file. My code works perfectly when running the program within IntelliJ IDEA, but when I create a .jar file and run it, it gives a "File not found" error. What can I do to make the code work both in the IDE as well as in the jar file?

Comment: If the file is placed as read-only "resource" on the class path (in the jar), you can get it as InputStream like Jon Skeet's answer. File is just for the operating system file system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to load the file as a *resource*. You can use [`Class.getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) or [`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-); each will give return an `InputStream` for the resource.

Once you've got an `InputStream`, wrap it in an `InputStreamReader` (specifying the appropriate encoding) to read text from it.

If you need to *sometimes* read from an arbitrary file and *sometimes* read from a resource, it's probably best to use separate paths to either create a `FileInputStream` for the file or one of the methods above for a resource, then do everything else the same way after that.

Here's an example which prints each line from `resources/names.txt` which should be bundled in the same jar file as the code:

```
package example;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                Test.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/names.txt"),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am struggling to understand what you mean some places here. Could you edit your post and add the actual code you would use? Thanks.

Comment: @Mikkel: I've added an example, although I suspect with some research you could have got there for yourself.

Answer (score -3):

try to change

> File file = new File("res/movies.txt");

to

> File file = new File("res/movies.jar");

this of course assumes the filename is movies.jar

Comment: No, the point is that the text file is *within* the jar file.